# Existence of a Blaschke product with an added boundary condition.

Tags: complex-analysis, interpolation, infinite-product

Suppose we have a sequence of distinct complex numbers $\{a_n\}$ such that $a_n\rightarrow 1$ and the $a_n$ satisfy the Blaschke condition $\sum (1-|a_n|)<\infty$.  Does there exist a Blaschke product $B$ such that $B(a_n)=0$ for each $n$ and $B(1)=1$?

I know that there is a Blaschke product $B$ for which $B(a_n)=0$ for all $n$, and my question is about what control we have over choosing certain boundary values of $B$. Can we ever guarantee that $B(1)$ exists, and if so, can we choose its value?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does your series $\sum_n (1 - |a_n|)$ converge hust conditionally, or absolutely? Or do you think it matters?

Comment: Does your  summation series converge or just have a  bounded set of  finite partial sums?

Comment: What do you mean by $B(1)$? Since the zeros of $B$ accumulate at $z=1$, there is no chance that $B$ is (can be extended to) a holomorphic function in a neighbourhood of $1$. So you must specify in what way you want to consider boundary values of $B$. You may be interested in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5331

Comment: @mrf A Blaschke product has the form $B(z)=\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\overline{a_n}}{|a_n|}\frac{a_n-z}{1-\overline{a_n}z}$. If each $a_n$ is real, then since $\frac{\overline{a_n}}{|a_n|}\frac{a_n-z}{1-\overline{a_n}z}=-1$ for all $n$, $B(1)$ doesn't exist. But if instead  $B(z)=\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z-a_n}{1-\overline{a_n}z}$ is the interpolating Blaschke product, then $B(1)=1$. So an infinite Blaschke product in this scenario need not be holomorphic in a neighborhood of $1$. But can we choose a Blaschke product for which $B(1)$ exists?